# How to call a variable inside a listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have displayed each time you click on a button a new textbox with 'Step n' in it : https://jsfiddle.net/askhfu7m/1/

```
 var x = 1;
 $("#323").val("Step 1");
 $("#add").click(function (e) {
   x++;
   $("#items").append('<div><input type="text" name="input[]" id="323" value="Step" + x + ":" >');
});
```

However, it seems like the x is not taken into account in the listener.

Could someone please help me ?

Thanks !!

Comment: That `$x` is going to be completely ignored by JavaScript.

Comment: It was a mistake I corrected it but I still have this problem, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (notice the `'` before and after x):

```
$("#items").append('<div><input type="text" name="input[]" id="323" value="Step' + x + ':" >');
```